# How to make fonts loads correctly

Tags: css, fonts

I have a problem with importing fonts into my app. I tried this but this is not working idk why this is not working or something gone wrong.

Here is my scss file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "OpenSansBold";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;

  src: url("../../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.eot");
  src: url("../../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("../../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("../../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.svg#OpenSansExtrabold") format("svg");
}
```

And here is my file structure:

[image]

And console gives me below:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost/webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.woff2
(index):1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost/webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.woff
(index):1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Please paste the error as text in the post.

Comment: If you load this font directly from google (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) probably solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code. I guess it will help you

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'OpenSansBold';
      src: url('../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.eot');
      src: local('☺'), url('../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.woff') format('woff'), url('../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../webfonts/opensans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.svg') format('svg');
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 800;
    }
```